# Web Application doesn't work after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have create a web application. Also I create a controller named person, when I'm deploy my project and running example `http://localhost:1392/api/Person`

I'm getting return value from controller.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

// GET: api/Person/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}

// POST: api/Person
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}

// PUT: api/Person/5
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
{
}

// DELETE: api/Person/5
public void Delete(int id)
{
}
```

When I'm publish my web application example in path C:/www

And trying to host this folder from iis7 I can't use above URL. I'm getting error 404 Not found
"`http://192.168.0.214:8081/api/Person`"

IIS7 Image:
[image: IIS7 Image]

And here is my error

Image error:
[image: Image error]

Comment: try "http://192.168.0.214:8081/[NameOfTheApplicationInIIS]/api/Person"

Answer (score 2):

Your url is incorrect

Change

```
http://192.168.0.214:8081/api/Person
```

To

```
http://192.168.0.214:8081/FirstWebPage/api/Person
```

Comment: I' getting the same error HTTP Error 404 - File or Directory not found"

Comment: Is there something that i need to enable or disable from iis7? Also i dont know if this is matter, but there is no folder api inside my path

Comment: No. what you mean? My publish method is file system

Comment: Does it work if you add it as an application under the `Default Web Site` in IIS? Rather than a separate website like you have